# Epson scanner requires libjpeg version 6 -where & how can I find this?

Tags: scanner, libraries, epson, jpeg

Using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Release. I installed Epson Image Scan! and apparently there's a known problem that doesn't allow saving scans as jpeg unless a lib is installed. I quote the FAQ:

----- quote -----

Image Scan! for Linux: I cannot save to JPEG

FAQ ID : LS00001
Created : 2009.10.30
Last modified : 2011.10.13

Saving to JPEG is disabled when a compatible version of the JPEG library is not detected on your system. Please install libjpeg version 6 in order to restore the ability to save to JPEG.

We have confirmed that this problem occurs in the following distributions:

```
Mandriva Linux 2010
Mandriva Linux 2010.1
Mandriva Linux 2011
openSUSE 11.3
Ubuntu 12.04
```

----- end quote -----

I've been searching the web and forums for a clue where to find this lib and how to install it without luck. I've found and installed libjpeg-turbo (8, I believe) but this didn't enable the jpeg file format in the app; it stays greyed out.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I found it. It's a package called **libjpeg62**, [available here](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/i386/libjpeg62/download) or [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/i386/libjpeg62/download). Second link appears newer and specially for Ubuntu. The scanner started saving as JPEG as soon as I installed the package and rebooted.

PS, sorry for the duped account. Dear namesake Jorge Castro, can you merge them?